# ECS cluster services are not automatically communicating with EC2 machine running on CentOS 8-1 OS with out adding the IP address every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ECS cluster with 18 microservices running on it And 3 of the services use another service running in another EC2 instance which is in the same VPC running with CentOS 8-1 OS, Every time when I deploy new changes for the 3 microservices I have to add the 3 services machine IP address to the ec2 security group of CentOS 8-1 OS machine.

I have already added the cluster security group to the EC2 machine still it does not work.